# How to add floating numbers as hours, and output hours with minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, sql

I have simple problem I am having time in double format. i.e.
1.20 hr. 2.30 hr. 3.40 hr.

I want to add them  as hours of time not as floating numbers i.e. to base 60 .
for example

1.20+2.30+3.40=7.30 hrs (correct)

1.20+2.30+3.40=6.90 (incorrect)

I want it in both SQL and C#, currently I am using custom made functions from both sides.
I want know any easiest way to do it.

If I am storing it in wrong format so please tell me how to do this right way,
basically I am getting difference between two datetimes as float number.

All possible solutions are welcome.

Comment: why not post the existing code?

Comment: For reference, "1.20 hr" is an hour and 12 minutes.  "1:20:00" is an hour and 20 minutes.  You make them look like regular base 10 numbers, and they're gonna get treated that way.

Comment: Why do you need it in SQL too? When you have to deal with nonsense formats, its better to turn them into something sensible ASAP, rather than keep them in that format. Keep the nonsense at the layer where you interface with the process that requires this format, and sensible data in the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no "fast" (read: built in) way. You will have to do it yourself.

- Split the numbers: the "whole number" part is the hour, the fraction (x 100) is the minutes
- add hours and minutes separately
- get "whole hours" from the minutes count and adjust both hour and minute count
- add the parts together: hours + minutes/100

Comment: ie what i am doing roight now

Answer (score 0):

```
double wholeHours = Math.Floor(timeVal);
TimeSpan realTime = new TimeSpan(wholeHours, (timeSpan - wholeHours) * 100 / 60;
```

You say "sql" which would suggest using the TIME datatype, however I'm guessing (since its most common with C#) that you mean SQLServer, which alas doesn't support the TIME datatype until 2008, so may not be available to you, in which case you'll have to keep using a float, and set it to the real number of hours with

```
FLOOR(timeVal) + (timeVal - FLOOR(timeVal)) * 100 / 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that in SQL.  The `ConvertedData` subquery splits your time format into minutes and hours.  The outer query sums them together, and converts them back to your float format:

```
select  sum(hours) + sum(minutes) / 60 as TotalHours
,       sum(minutes) % 60 as TotalMinutes
,       sum(hours) + sum(minutes) / 60 + sum(minutes) % 60.0 / 100 as YourDt
from    (
        select  cast(YourDt % 1 * 100 as int) as minutes
        ,       cast(YourDt as int) as hours
        from    (
                select  1.2 as YourDt
                union all
                select  2.3
                union all
                select  3.4
                ) SourceData
        ) ConvertedData
```

This prints:

```
TotalHours  TotalMinutes  YourDt
7           30            7.300000
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try changing the format to something more sensible. Either total number of minutes or one field for hours and one for minutes. It will make your life easier.

Comment: i cant because it is not in my hand

Answer (score 0):

Well, a .NET assembly can be called as stored proc within SQL server, hence your solution can be written in C#

I would use the TimeSpan object for this kind of calculation as shown already by Jon, with some added comfort:

```
public static TimeSpan AddMinutes(this TimeSpan span, double mins)
{
  return span.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins));
}

public static string ToHourAndMins(this TimeSpan span)
{
  return string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", Math.Truncate(span.TotalHours), span.Minutes);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
ts = ts.AddMinutes(45);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToHourAndMins());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really a bad idea to calculate datetime in your way. Here is what you want:

```
    double original = 1.55d+2.9d+3.48d;
    double carry = (int)(original * 100) % 100 / 60;
    double result = original + carry - carry / 100 * 60;
```